# drf-yasg hide title property

Tags: python, django, swagger, drf-yasg

[image]

So as shown in the image, is there any way to hide the 'title' property foreach item? I don't really see the purpose of these titles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on `drf_yasg` [documentation](https://drf-yasg.readthedocs.io/en/stable/custom_spec.html?highlight=title) **you should first define a class** to have a **schema without title** for each API you can define a class as below:

```py
from drf_yasg.inspectors import FieldInspector

class NoSchemaTitleInspector(FieldInspector):
   def process_result(self, result, method_name, obj, **kwargs):
      # remove the `title` attribute of all Schema objects
      if isinstance(result, openapi.Schema.OR_REF):
         # traverse any references and alter the Schema object in place
         schema = openapi.resolve_ref(result, self.components)
         schema.pop('title', None)

         # no ``return schema`` here, because it would mean we always generate
         # an inline `object` instead of a definition reference

      # return back the same object that we got - i.e. a reference if we got a reference
      return result
```

Now you should define **a class** to use `drf_yasg` **for removing title automatically**, therefore you need to define a class like below:

```py
class NoTitleAutoSchema(SwaggerAutoSchema):
   field_inspectors = [NoSchemaTitleInspector] + swagger_settings.DEFAULT_FIELD_INSPECTORS
```

Here like the below snippet you can **hide all title** properties from your API viewset:

```py
class ArticleViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
   swagger_schema = NoTitleAutoSchema
   ...
```